# Prove that $AD+CD=AB$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In $\triangle ABC$, $AC=BC$, $\angle ACB=100^{\circ}$. $D$ is a point on $BC$ such that $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC$. Prove that $AD+CD=AB$.

[image]

---

This post serves a purpose of recording my solution to this geometry problem, without trigonometry. *This isn't a question waiting to be answered.*

Feel free to comment or post you thoughts or, if any, alternative answers. If you've spotted mistakes in my answer, you can point them out as well.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Let $L$ be a point on $AB$ such that $AD=AL$ and P be the reflection of point $L$ over $AD$.

By simple angle chasing you can get $\angle DPC=80^o$ and $\angle DCP = 80^o$ then you can find relationship $CD=DP$. Also in $\triangle DLB$ you can get $\angle LDB=40^o$ and $\angle LBD=40^o$ and $DL=LB$

And also by properties of a reflection, you can find out that $DL=DP=CD$

Then finally you can get,

$\boxed{AB=AD+CD}$

P.S:- As $AD$ is the bisector of $\angle BAC$, DCP will be a straight line

Answer (score 2):

[image]

---

Construct $AE=AB$ such that $D$ is on $AE$. With $\angle EAB=20^{\circ}$ we immediately have $\angle ABE=\angle AEB=80^{\circ}$, and thus $\angle DBE=40^{\circ}$. This implies that $BD$ bisects $\angle ABE$.

Extend $AC$ and $BE$. Let $F$ be their intersection. It's clear that $D$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABF$, and we obtain $\angle BFD=30^{\circ}$.

Notice that $\angle BCF=180^{\circ}-\angle ACB=80^{\circ}$. Hence $\angle BCF=\angle BED$, and by AA similarity, $$\triangle BED\sim\triangle BCF,$$ implying $$\frac{BE}{BC}=\frac{BD}{BF}\implies\frac{BE}{BD}=\frac{BC}{BF}.$$ By SAS similarity we can say $$\triangle BEC\sim\triangle BDF,$$ yielding $\angle BCE=\angle BFD=30^{\circ}$. Note that $\angle CDE=\angle ADB=120^{\circ}$, so $\angle CED=30^{\circ}$, which implies $CD=DE$. Finally, $$AB=AE=AD+DE=AD+CD.$$

Comment: I suggest a shorter version:-   In $\triangle BCF, \angle BCF = 80^0$ and in $\triangle AEB, \angle AEB = 80^0$. Then, CDEF is cyclic. Hence, $\angle DCE  = \angle DFE = \angle CFD = \angle DEC$.

Comment: @Mick Well spotted! Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AC=L$, since $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles, we have $AB=2L\cos(40^\circ)$. Next, use sine law:

$$\frac{AC}{\sin(60^\circ)}=\frac{CD}{\sin(20^\circ)}=\frac{AD}{\sin(100^\circ)}\Rightarrow CD=\frac{\sin(20^\circ)}{\sin(60^\circ)}L,~~AD=\frac{\sin(100^\circ)}{\sin(60^\circ)}L$$

We get: $$AD+CD=\frac{\sin(100^\circ)+\sin(20^\circ)}{\sin(60^\circ)}L=\frac{2\sin(60^\circ)\cos(40^\circ)}{\sin(60^\circ)}L=2L\cos(40^\circ)=AB$$